# Why does my script only work when i have something in the clipboard?

Tags: applescript

I have a (long) Applescript to open up a VPN connection. However, it stalls if i do not have text in the clipboard, and i can't seem to understand why.

What i'm trying to accomplish is moving whatever is in my clipboard (if there is anything) to a temp variable, put the password in the clipboard so that i can paste it into the login window, and finally put the clipboard back.

This is the (i think) relevant portion of my script:

```
open_vpn_connection(vpn_name, user_name, app_name, window_name)
set pass_word to getPassword(keychain_name)
local clipBefore
set clipBefore to the clipboard
set the clipboard to pass_word
delay 0.5
tell application "System Events"
    keystroke "v" using command down
    keystroke return
end tell
delay 0.5
set the clipboard to clipBefore
```

So basically, unless I have something in the clipboard before running the script, it hangs. Does anybody know why?

Comment: I think you're going to have to include in your question the handler (subroutine) `getPassword()`

Comment: Well, i just get it from keychain, it's always the same and always returns a string. That subroutine is not the problem. It's something to do with what i do with the clipboard, since it only fails if my clipboard is empty.

Comment: I've tested the portion of code you shared and, whatever the issue is, it's not coming from that.  If you're still experiencing the problem and would like help getting to the bottom of it, you'll need to share you entire script.  If it's very long, I recommend using an online pastebin and sharing the link.

Comment: CJK, it is. Please read my answer and see what you think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I have dug around a bit, and i think i have found the cause. For starters, i'd like to add that this used to work for several years, but stopped working in a mac update about a year ago.

Here is a "proof-of-concept"-script i am using in Script Editor:

```
set clipBefore to the clipboard
log clipBefore
set the clipboard to "banana"
log (the clipboard)
set the clipboard to clipBefore
log (the clipboard)
```

If i reboot my machine, open up script editor the first thing i do, and run my script i get this in the logs:

```
error "An error of type -25133 has occurred." number -25133
```

I looked around, and that error code is

```
badPasteboardFlavorErr = -25133, /* item flavor does not exist*/
```

,which tells me that there is some issue with the system clipboard handling? I cannot say exactly when it happens, but it sometimes also happens if my machine has been locked for a long enough while, i unlock it and run the script.

The solution is always to just do ctrl+c of something and then run the script again.

**I solved my script (which of course does a lot of things before and after my partial code) by adding try catch around the clipboard stuff:**

```
local clipBefore
set clipBefore to ""
try
    set clipBefore to the clipboard
end try 
set the clipboard to pass_word
```

Since it only throws an exception when there is nothing in the clipboard anyway, it now works every time :)

Comment: Thanks, this helped me a lot. For me it looks like that error `-25133` is also occurring when the clipboard contains some special sort of rich content.